$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$; $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$; $(c_1,c_2)$. The total number of combinations with given condition

You are given three classes of letters: $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$; $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$; $(c_1,c_2)$. THe total number of combinations which can be made with these letters when no two of the same class enter into any combination is:

My answer:
$\bigg[{4\choose 0}+{4\choose 1}+....+{4\choose 4}\bigg]\cdot \bigg[{3\choose0}+{3\choose1}+..+{3\choose3}\bigg]\cdot\bigg[{2\choose0}+{2\choose1}+{2\choose2}\bigg]-1=2^4\cdot2^3\cdot 2^2-1$ But given answer is $59$

The rules are not clear.  You are selecting either $1$ from each type or $0$?   Something else?

Note:  my interpretation gives the official answer of $59$ just by summing the $8$ cases.  Your computation appears to allow multiple selections from each class, which is against the rules.

@lulu given questions is as i typed. My solution is first thought came to my mind. Given solution is $5\times4\times3-1$ but this method is applicable when objects are identical. How can they select this way.

Yes, I understand the given question, it's just that your method is inappropriate.  You allow multiple $a's$ in your count, for instance.

Your computation allows for multiple selections within a given class, counter to the rules.
A quick way to do it:  add an element $\emptyset$ to each class...choosing that one is then the same as omitting that class.  We see that, post addition, there are $5$ in class $1$, $4$ in class $2$ and $3$ in class $3$.  Thus there are $$5\times 4\times 3=60$$ possible combinations.
Presumably the difference between $60$ and the official $59$ is that the empty combination is excluded from the official solution.

I got the concept. Thanks
